# How to create custom imageview with image load listener in android?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I want to load images into `gridView` and want to show `progress bar` during loading and dismiss it when the loading finished.

How to create `image load listener` for the images without using third party libraries? 
Suggest me any sample code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Create a common class CustomNetworkImageView

```
public class CustomNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {

    private Bitmap mLocalBitmap;

    private boolean mShowLocal;

    public void setLocalImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            mShowLocal = true;
        }
        this.mLocalBitmap = bitmap;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mShowLocal = false;
        super.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
    }

    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (mShowLocal) {
            setImageBitmap(mLocalBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

In your xml use like this

```
<urpackagename.CustomNetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/urDrawable" />
```

In your Activity or fragment initialize customImage View

```
public CustomNetworkImageView userImage;
userImage = (CustomNetworkImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
```